# CPU usage of Python executable abnormally high during subprocess.run call

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a Python script that runs a sequence of long-running executables using `subprocess.run`. For example:

```
subprocess.run(['cpfind', '--multirow', '--celeste', '-o', pto_path, pto_path], check=True)
```

For some reason, when I inspect the CPU usage of the running processes, the Python executable appears to be utilizing as much of the CPU as the executable being called. Here's a screenshot of the `top` readout (the machine has a single-core).

[image]

I'm wondering if this readout is correct, and if so, how I might ameliorate the problem.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm guessing this is just how `top` reports on the parent process.